# How to convert strtotime format for calculating time elapsed

Tags: php, datetime, time, date-difference

I am trying to put time elapsed in the comment box.

Tried using below code, however it is giving me time elapsed as 45 years.

Here is my code

```
    $data = $row['created_on'];
    $time = strtotime('$data');
    <li>
        <span class="author">
            <?php echo $row['name']; ?>
        </span>
        <span class="time">
            <?php echo ''.humanTiming($time).' ago'; ?>
        </span><br/>
        <div class="c_content">
            <?php echo $row['comment']; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
<?php
function humanTiming ($time){ 
    $time = time() - $time; // to get the time since that moment
    $tokens = array (
        31536000 => 'year',
        2592000 => 'month',
        604800 => 'week',
        86400 => 'day',
        3600 => 'hour',
        60 => 'minute',
        1 => 'second'
    );
    foreach ($tokens as $unit => $text) {
        if ($time < $unit) continue;
        $numberOfUnits = floor($time / $unit);
        return $numberOfUnits.' '.$text.(($numberOfUnits>1)?'s':'');
    }
}
```

Comment: $data = $row['created_on']; is that really $data not $date? 
$time = strtotime('$date'); remove the single quote. it should be $time = strtotime($date);

Comment: The unix epoch started about 45 years ago. Which means somewhere where your trying to input a date is returning false or '0'. Which is the start of the unix timestamp, which is 45 years ago. My first thought was removing the single quotes from `$time = strtotime('$date');` like @DarkZ3ro11 said.

Comment: @Dish_Rex Yes i tried removing single quotes as well and it gives blank output. DarkZ3r011 sorry was trying something and forgot to change it back.

Comment: did you try to output $row['created_on']? maybe its empty or the query is returning empty or false, i tried your code and its working, i tried this date format 03/12/2015,

Comment: @DarkZ3ro11 yes it giving me the right timestamp. output with $row['created_on'] is 2015-03-13 01:28:05

Comment: I tested it too and  when I put in the value of 2015-03-13 01:28:05 to the $data variable it works. `$data = '2015-03-10 01:28:05'; $time = strtotime($data); ` but when I put the single quotation marks on the `$time = strtotime('$data')` I get '45 years ago'.

Comment: what's the result if you echo time() - $time ? when i tested the code it returned empty when time() - $time value is negative,, just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

```
function timeAgo($time_ago)
{
    $time_ago = strtotime($time_ago);
    $cur_time   = time();
    $time_elapsed   = $cur_time - $time_ago;
    $seconds    = $time_elapsed ;
    $minutes    = round($time_elapsed / 60 );
    $hours      = round($time_elapsed / 3600);
    $days       = round($time_elapsed / 86400 );
    $weeks      = round($time_elapsed / 604800);
    $months     = round($time_elapsed / 2600640 );
    $years      = round($time_elapsed / 31207680 );
    // Seconds
    if($seconds <= 60){
        return "now";
    }
    //Minutes
    else if($minutes <=60){
        if($minutes==1){
            return "1mn";
        }
        else{
            return "$minutes"."mn";
        }
    }
    //Hours
    else if($hours <=24){
        if($hours==1){
            return "1h";
        }else{
            return "$hours"."h";
        }
    }
    //Days
    else if($days <= 7){
        if($days==1){
            return "1j";
        }else{
            return "$days"."j";
        }
    }
    //Weeks
    else if($weeks <= 4.3){
        if($weeks==1){
            return "1sm";
        }else{
            return "$weeks"."sm";
        }
    }
    //Months
    else if($months <=12){
        if($months==1){
            return "1m";
        }else{
            return "$months"."m";
        }
    }
    //Years
    else{
        if($years==1){
            return "1a";
        }else{
            return "$years"."a";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so the problem is in your variable value , echo to see it's value

Comment: Yes even i think so but not able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a smart way to get your human timing...

Note: This solution doesn't appreciate any timezone declarations, you'll need to add this to your [DateTime declarations](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php).

```
$data="2015-03-13 01:28:05";  // declare your input
$then=new DateTime($data);    // feed input to DateTime
$now=new DateTime();         // get DateTime for Now
$diff=(array)$then->diff($now);      // calculate the difference & cast as array
$labels=array("y"=>"year","m"=>"month","d"=>"day","h"=>"hour","i"=>"minute","s"=>"second");
$readable="";       // declare as empty string
// filter the $diff array to only include the desired elements and loop
foreach(array_intersect_key($diff,$labels) as $k=>$v){
    if($v>0){  // only add non-zero values to $readable
        $readable.=($readable!=""?", ":"")."$v {$labels[$k]}".($v>1?"s":"");
        //  use comma-space as glue | show value | show unit | pluralize when necessary
    }
}
echo "$readable ago";
// e.g. 2 years, 9 days, 23 hours, 1 minute, 7 seconds ago
```

See for yourself in this working [Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8524fe05388eb6f5370cd3b6039368651128d44b).

If you are just looking for a function:

```
function humanTiming($time){
    $then=new DateTime($time);
    $now=new DateTime();
    $diff=(array)$then->diff($now);
    $labels=array("y"=>"year","m"=>"month","d"=>"day","h"=>"hour","i"=>"minute","s"=>"second");
    $readable="";
    foreach(array_intersect_key($diff,$labels) as $k=>$v){
        if($v>0){
            $readable.=($readable!=""?", ":"")."$v {$labels[$k]}".($v>1?"s":"");
        }
    }
    return "$readable ago";
}

...
    <span class="time">
        <?php echo humanTiming($row['created_on']); ?>
    </span><br/>
...
```

Comment: @swap If my answer sufficiently solves your issue please award it the green tick (and perhaps an upvote for refining your process).  By selecting a best answer, your question will be removed from the unanswered questions list -- making SO more complete and helpful for future researchers.